# Create uuid and insert into Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, uuid

Please find the code below and Let me know how I create cassandra UUID and append it into SNO column. There is no sno column in CSV file. But I added sno column in the cassandra table. I have to populate sno with uuid of cassandra and insert into Cassandra Table along with the CSV data. Below is the code I have.

Scala Version: 2.11 Spark : 2.2

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import com.datastax


import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object dataframeset {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample1").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val rdd1 = sc.cassandraTable("tdata", "map3")
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark1 = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().master("local").config("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.0.1")
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark1.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema", "true").load("/Users/Desktop/del2.csv")
    import spark1.implicits._
    println("\nTop Records are:")
    df.show(1)

    val dfprev1 = df.select(col = "year", "StateAbbr")

    dfprev1.show(1)
  }
}
```

Needed Out put:

```
+---+----+---------+
|sno|year|StateAbbr|
+---+----+---------+
|  54d6e-29bb-11e5-b345-feff819cdc9f |2014|       US|
+---+----+---------+
only showing top 1 row
```